# Rails permit nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this nested form, `submitted_quiz` and `submitted_answers`. I'll add the basic layout of this form so you can understand it better:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @submitted_quiz]) do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :quiz_id, :value => @quiz.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => @quiz.name %>

<%= f.fields_for (:submitted_answers) do |ff| %>
<%= ff.hidden_field :question_id, :value => question.id %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

So as you can see, I need to permit `:quiz_id`, `:name` of `submitted_quiz` but I also need to permit the nested `:question_id` of `submitted_answers`. I know how to permit just one layer (`submitted_quiz`) but I'm confused on how to permit nested layers.

Comment: Use cocoon gem. For more, see https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it in two ways:

1.just permit all params

```
params.require(:submitted_quiz).permit!
```

2.or by names:

```
params.require(:submitted_quiz).permit(:quiz_id, :name, submitted_answers_attributes: [:question_id])
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'call' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f6e210ddba8> Did you mean? caller`. Do you know why?